# Import Issue in Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a cell value "80/90" in a .csv file.

While importing into Teradata using sql assistant, the value shows up as "?".

The dataype of the column given was CV (Character Variable Length).

How do I resolve this?

Comment: How are you importing this? The question mark is the default token used for NULL values.

Comment: Did you mean to include the tags for SQL Server and TSQL? This question seems to be about Teradata only?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the field datatype to text both in excel and your table (in which you are inserting the data), it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use varchar as the datatype instead of CV.